# Wait for modal 'please wait' to close

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

What is the standard Cypress-way to wait for a 'please wait' modal to close?

Easy to check it is there, but without using `cy.wait(ms)`, how can I cause Cypress to keep checking for a period of time, to see if the element has been removed from the DOM, or made invisible?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can simply use `should` to assert it doesn't exist, and Cypress will wait for the element until it's removed from DOM. If you need to override the default `4s` timeout, you can pass it to the previous command:

```
cy.get( selector, { timeout: 10000 }).should("not.exist");
```

Answer (score 2):

try using `cy.get(selector).should("not.be.visible");`  it worked for me